# jquery co-ordinate problems on an image with in a absolute positioned div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css-position

I have a problem recording x and y co-ordinates using jQuery/javascript, on an image that is with in a 'position: absolute div' container.

Basically what is supposed to happen is somewhere in the image is clicked, and a div containing information is placed on those co-ordinates.

However when the image's div container has a position absolute, the x and y co-ordinates are off, but that needs to be there to overlay the image with over divs, unless someone can think of a better way?

below is my code, any help appreciated

```
<style>
    #image_container {position: absolute}
    #test_img {}
    .image_dot { height: 5px; width: 5px; background-color: red; position: absolute; }
</style>

<div id="image_container">
    <img src="mrt.jpg" id="test_img" /> 
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
      $("#test_img").click(function(event) {
        var x = event.pageX - this.offsetLeft;
        var y = event.pageY - this.offsetTop;
        $("#image_container").append('<div class="image_dot" id="uniqueid" style="display: none;">Some text</div>');
        $("#unqiueid").css("top",x+"px").css("left",y+"px").show();
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Are you trying to position the new element at the top-left of the image no matter what? Or right on the wherever the user clicks?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this will work since I don't have time to set up a test-case, but I think if possible you should just let the click() event bubble up to the `body` element. For example:

```
$(body).click(function(e) {
    var x = event.pageX;
    var y = event.pageY;
    $("body").append('<div class="image_dot" id="uniqueid" style="display: none;">Some text</div>');
    $("#unqiueid").css("top",x+"px").css("left",y+"px").show();
}
```

If everything is just being positioned absolute anyway (and not relative), it shouldn't matter, and I believe you should get better pageX and pageY values by using the `body` (or maybe `window`?) element.

As I said, though, I haven't had a chance to actually test this. Let me know if it works!

Comment: Sorry I should have mentioned I wanted to store the offsetted co-ordinates in the database for future. Would prefer to do it with out storing the image's co-ordinates and the page co-ordinates, but yes this does work otherwise.